# .pow - failed to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-pow

I have been using pow for years but all of a sudden it's not working for me. I'm at my wits end trying to debug this. When I try to visit my .dev/ domains I am getting simply `http://foo.dev/ failed to load` in the page title. The page content simply shows "no data received".

1. tried on the latest Chrome, Firefox and Safari.
2. tried deleting and recreating all symlinks
3. reinstalled pow
4. recreated gemsets
5. `touch tmp/restart.tmp`.

Strangely, `tail -f ~/Library/Logs/Pow/access.log` produces nothing when I try to visit `foo.dev`. Additionally, `~Library/Logs/Pow/apps/foo.log` does not exist.

I'm on OSX Mavericks (.pow worked on Mavericks before), using Ruby 2.0.0-p247, RVM, .ruby-version & .ruby-gemset.

**.powrc**

```
if [ -f "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm" ] && [ -f ".rvmrc" ]; then
  source "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm"
  source ".rvmrc"
fi
```

**.powenv**

```
# detect `$rvm_path`
if [ -z "${rvm_path:-}" ] && [ -x "${HOME:-}/.rvm/bin/rvm" ]
then rvm_path="${HOME:-}/.rvm"
fi
if [ -z "${rvm_path:-}" ] && [ -x "/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm" ]
then rvm_path="/usr/local/rvm"
fi

# load environment of current project ruby
if
  [ -n "${rvm_path:-}" ] &&
  [ -x "${rvm_path:-}/bin/rvm" ] &&
  rvm_project_environment=`"${rvm_path:-}/bin/rvm" . do rvm env --path 2>/dev/null` &&
  [ -n "${rvm_project_environment:-}" ] &&
  [ -s "${rvm_project_environment:-}" ]
then
  echo "RVM loading: ${rvm_project_environment:-}"
  \. "${rvm_project_environment:-}"
else
  echo "RVM project not found at: $PWD"
fi
```

I've been trying to debug this for over 5 days now and I cannot figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up fixing it for me:

```
$ rvm cleanup all 
$ rvm get stable
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is

1. Reinstalling RVM
2. Reinstalling POW
3. Adding the details to the .powrc file from POW's page
4. Adding this path before the content of the .powrc file :

.

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```